# IE10/11 shows vertical scrollbar into nothing?

Tags: html, css, animation, overflow

If you try my [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aqa6J/) for Navtabs in Firefox or Chrome, only the `Other Stuff` Navtab creates a scrollbar due to the overflow - which works as it should.

But if you try tit again in IE10/11 it creates a scrollbar on every tab.
Seems like it takes the length from `Other Stuff`. I tried to google it, changed the overflows on `body` , `html, body` etc. but either

- it isn't scrollable
- the scrollbar isn't visable but you still scroll into "nothing"
- or the scrollbar is visable and you scroll into nothing..

I'd appreciate any help if this can be done!

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are changing the opacity, but not essentially getting rid of the element.

If you use `display` instead of `opacity`, it works as intended. However the transitions go.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W2CUd/)

I'm not skilled enough to get transitions working as well as fixing the problem. Sorry :(